# Java 11 Http Client default thread pool size

Tags: httpclient, java-11

I was recently working of Java 11's http client in which, we can pass an executor if needed or else it will use a default executor service.

I tried to search for the default executors thread pool size. But couldn't find the size.
The send(...) method of Http Client internally calls sendAsync(...) and then blocks the calling thread using get() of Completable future.

I was looking for synchronous call, but it seems it is using asynchronous method with blocking.

So the questions are

1. What is the default thread pool size used in the http client.
2. When should I pass my own thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Q. What is the default thread pool size used in the http client?

A. As per open jdk implementation [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/HttpClientImpl.java#L458), by default it uses a newCachedThreadPool.

Cached Thread pool does not have a thread pool size as mentioned in javadoc quoted below.

> **Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available**. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. **Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache**. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources. Note that pools with similar properties but different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created using `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructors.

Q. When should I pass my own thread pool?

A. If one need a different behavior than the default thread pool, then one should specify that while building the http client.